# Django what is the most effective way of subsetting a queryset?

Tags: django

Since each queryset is [unique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#filtered-querysets-are-unique), what is the best way of subsetting a large queryset without generate too many sql queries in a loop?

For instance, I need to produce a report which requires me to loop through all of the data in a database:

```
for user in users:
    notes = Note.objects.filter(owner=user.id)
    for note in notes:
        answers = Answer.filter(note_id = note.id)
        for answer in answers:
            #do something
```

As you can already see how bad this loop will be since each filter statement creates a queryset which hits the database.

What am I suppose to do in this situation to avoid calling the database thousands of times?

Comment: If you need to iterate through every Answer, why do you need to filter by Note at all? Why not directly through Answer.objects.all()?

Comment: Because I didn't link the Answer model with the User model, which means I don't know which answer belongs to which User. But I did link Answer to Note and Note to User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `users` is QuerySet, then

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(note__owner__in=users)
```

UPDATE: If you want to do something with `Answer`'s `note` and `owner`, then

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(note__owner__in=users).select_related('note', 'note__owner')
```

It requires one query.

Comment: yes, users is a queryset.  Please see my comments for the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
answer = Answer.objects.filter(note__owner__in = user_ids)
```

Comment: With this approach, the number of database hits grows as the number of users increases. I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this without creating any queryset in a loop. Maybe converting a queryset which contains all of the information to a dictionary and loop through the dictionary.

Comment: I will edit, assuming you start with a list of ids. If you want all the users, there were no point to filtering

Comment: .select_related('note', 'note__owner') solved the problem as suggested by @f43d65 but thanks for your help though!